# WCF REST Service: Exception when accessed by Jersey and TransferMode = Streamed

Tags: wcf, rest, jersey

I have a WCF-REST service with one method which returns a string:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/getastring/")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetAString(string input);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetAString(string input)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("GetAString");
        return input;
    }
}
```

The service is hosted with a *WebHttpBinding* and the *TransferMode* is set to **Streamed**

```
ServiceHost streamedHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost/streamed"));
WebHttpBinding streamedBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
streamedBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
ServiceEndpoint streamedEndpoint = streamedHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), streamedBinding, string.Empty);
streamedEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ErrorWebHttpBehavior());
streamedHost.Open();
```

When the service is accessed with a .NET-Client everything is fine.
When I use a Java-Client with Jersey, the following exception occurs:

> An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

The only happens when the *TransferMode* is set to **Streamed**.

The following Java code is used:

```
Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost").build());

String result = service.path("regular/getastring").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(String.class, "123");
System.out.println(result);
```

Is there a way to consume the streamed WCF service without this exception?

Sample project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21096596/WCF-Jersey.zip

Comment: can you share full stacktrace? Are you sure that your service is running on port 80? (if not, add it to URI: "http://localhost:[port]")

Comment: Service is running on port 80. But every other port is possible as well.   Stacktrace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage.OnClose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParameterList(Object[] parameters)

Comment: I meant client side exception..

Comment: you can also try service.path("regular/getastring").post(InputStream.class, "123")

Comment: Thanks for your hint to InputStream. Will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not appear if streaming is only enabled for the response.
Setting `TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse;` in the binding configuration fixes the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

almost 2 years later.. here my answer:

i had the very same problem with the very same error, but you can't solve using `StreamedResponse`. As stated from MSDN [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using `StreamedResponse` will enable `Streaming` for **Response** and `Buffered` for **Request**.

So.. it *will* work, but in *buffered mode*. If you're transfering large files (like 10gb) your program will preload it in RAM before sending.

Now, if your problem is the same as the one i had, i can tell its only client-side. I'm pretty sure that your java code works for file smaller than 65.536 byte. Thats because you need to change your `maxReceivedMessageSize` property on the client for downloads!

Its a `long` type, so you can set to a max of **9223372036854775807** bytes, but i don't think you will ever need that much!

Hope this helps someone who, like me, wasted 1 day of life in this situation!